# Stored procs breaking overnight

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan

We are running MS SQL 2005 and we have been experiencing a very peculiar problem the past few days.

I have two procs, one that creates an hourly report of data.  And another that calls it, puts its results in a temp table, and does some aggregations, and returns a summary.

They work fine...until the next morning.

The next morning, suddenly the calling report, complains about an invalid column name.

The fix, is simply a recompile of the calling proc, and all works well again.

How can this happen?  It's happened three nights in a row since moving these procs into production.

EDIT: It appears, that it's not a recompile that is needed of the caller (summary) proc.  I was just able to fix the problem by executing the callee (hourly) proc.  Then executing the summary proc.  This makes less sense than before.

EDIT2:
The hourly proc is rather large, and I'm not posting it here in it's entirety.  But, at the end, it does a SELECT INTO, then conditionally, returns the appropriate result(s) from the created temp table.

```
Select      [large column list]
    into    #tmpResults
    From    #DailySales8
    Where   datepart(hour,RowStartTime) >= @StartHour
    and datepart(hour,RowStartTime) < @EndHour
    and datepart(hour, RowStartTime) <= @LastHour

IF @UntilHour IS NOT NULL 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpResults WHERE datepart(hour, RowEndTime) = @UntilHour) BEGIN
        SELECT      * 
            FROM    #tmpResults
            WHERE   datepart(hour, RowEndTime) = @UntilHour
END ELSE IF @JustLastFullHour = 1 BEGIN
        DECLARE @MaxHour INT
        SELECT @MaxHour = max(datepart(hour, RowEndTime)) FROM #tmpResults

        IF @LastHour > 24 SELECT @LastHour = @MaxHour

        SELECT      * 
            FROM    #tmpResults
            WHERE   datepart(hour, RowEndTime) = @LastHour

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN
            SELECT      * 
                FROM    #tmpResults
                WHERE   datepart(hour, RowEndTime) = @MaxHour
        END
END ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM #tmpResults
END
```

Then it drops all temp tables and ends.

The caller (Summary)

First creates a temp table #tmpTodaySales to store the results, the column list DOES MATCH the definition of #tmpResults in the other proc.  Then it ends up calling the hourly proc a couple times

```
    INSERT #tmpTodaysSales
        EXEC HourlyProc @LocationCode, @ReportDate, null, 1


    INSERT #tmpTodaysSales
        EXEC HourlyProc @LocationCode, @LastWeekReportDate, @LastHour, 0
```

I believe it is these calls that fail.  But recompiling the proc, or executing the hourly procedure outside of this, and then calling the summary proc fixes the problem.

Comment: Could you post the proc definition?

Comment: Can you post some code snippets to illustrate the problem? Is the "missing" column missing from the "report creation" proc results or from the temp table created by the "summary" proc?

Comment: Wild shot in the dark - negative number in a calc somewhere as result of trying to calculate the difference between 23:00 and 00:00?

Comment: It's not the proc definition that's the problem.  They are both good.  Once the caller (summary) is recompiled it works.  No changes are made to it, but the next day, it will be failing again.  Neither proc is changed.

Comment: @Paolo, I don't think so.  It doesn't actually run overnight.  The last run is at 2230, successfully, then it runs again, failing, at 1000 the next day.  And it will fail every single time, no matter the hour, until it's recompiled.

Comment: Not enough information to go on! How about the exact error message?

Comment: @Neil, the error is "Invalid column name 'RowEndTime'".  But that's not the point, the column exists.  The temp table has the column defined.  The proc WORKS as soon as it (summary) is recompiled.  The issue, is that SQL Server is losing it's execution plan (or something) overnight for no apparent reason.  They are brand new procs on this server as of Friday.  So they aren't being called by anything else.  There aren't any jobs messing with them.  They run fine at 2230, then the next day at 1000 the summary fails.  And keeps failing until it's recompiled.

Comment: How does the hourly report create its data? Does it save it to a new table, a temporary table, truncate and repopulate an "hourly report" table? Go on - post the procs! We may see what you haven't!

Comment: Can you schedule the jobs to run every hour?  It just sounds to me like the procedures break every second time they're run from the scheduler, so maybe run them every hour (or even every five minutes) and see if that is indeed the case.  If not, then maybe leave them on that schedule overnight and see when they break.  If it really is related to the date change, then you'd expect the first run after midnight to fail.  If it's related to something else, then at least you have a better chance to correlate it.

Comment: @TMN, it's not every second time, They get run for different people several times a day, and they will all work after I get them working in the morning.  But, the next day, all broken until a recompile.

Comment: Is it possible your temp table is getting deleted from tempdb overnight?  Can you verify that your hourly report is actually getting called before the summary?  I'm wondering if the SP loader is validating the metadata before calling the summary, discovering the table is missing, and just reporting the error without even running the summary.  If it won't mess up your data, maybe try scheduling the hourly report separately, just before the summary.

Comment: @TMN, The temp table is created in the summary proc.  Deleting it wouldn't be a problem.  And the temp tables the hourly proc are also, created IN the hourly proc.  There are no temp tables that are shared across procs or runs of the same proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two questions:

Does the schema of #DailySales8 vary at all? Does it have any direct/indirect dependence on the date of execution, or on any of the parameters supplied to HourlyProc?

Which execution of `INSERT #tmpTodaysSales EXEC HourlyProc ...`  in the summary fails - first or second?

Comment: No, the schema of #DailySales8 does not change.  And yes, it does directly depend on the date of execution.  It's creating up to the minute sales reports, so it uses the current date, or one passed in, to retrieve sales for.  I'm not sure which fails.

Comment: Turns out there was a hidden requirement between the two where they relied on results from each other.  bad design.  has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What do the overnight maintenance plans look like, and are there any other scheduled overnight jobs that run between 2230 and 1000 the next day? It's possible that step in the maintenance plan or another agent job is causing some kind of corruption that's breaking your SP.